# The destructuring in javascript ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript

I saw this example in ES6 [here](http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/index.html) (example for search.js). What does this syntax mean?

Interested in

```
import Api from '...'
```

full example

```
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import Api from '...'

// worker Saga: will be fired on USER_FETCH_REQUESTED actions
function* fetchUser(action) {
   try {
      const user = yield call(Api.fetchUser, action.payload.userId);
      yield put({type: "USER_FETCH_SUCCEEDED", user: user});
   } catch (e) {
      yield put({type: "USER_FETCH_FAILED", message: e.message});
   }
}
```

Comment: It is just pseudo code, in reality you would import your `Api` module

Comment: e.g. import Api from Api?

Comment: import from any module or file. e.g. `import Api from './Api'`. depends on you